# Выделяется ли уточнение?

Tags: пунктуация

Фраза такая: "13 мая текущего года состоится очередное, 13-е заседании Коллегии ЕЭК." Так вот, я озадачился: надо ли выделять запятыми "13-е" или "тринадцатое"? Это, вроде бы, уточнение...
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИЗ ОБЩЕЙ ТЕОРИИ

Прилагательные  могут находиться в следующих отношениях: а) неоднородные (нет запятой), б) однородные (разделяются запятыми), в) уточняющее определение выделяется запятыми.

РЕШЕНИЕ

В отношении прилагательных "очередной и тринадцатый" рассуждаем так:

А) Прилагательные не могут быть неоднородными, в противном случаем мы получим очередное заседание из  "ряда тринадцатых заседаний", поэтому без запятой не обойтись.

Б) Второе прилагательное по смыслу является уточняющим, и надо бы его обособить запятыми.

В) Однако для прилагательных такого рода предлагается другое решение: их считают уточняющими однородного типа и не обособляют, а разделяют запятыми.

Поэтому оформление фразы оставляем без изменения: "13 мая текущего года состоится очередное, 13-е заседании Коллегии ЕЭК."

ДЛЯ СРАВНЕНИЯ:

(1)Я хочу купить другой кожаный портфель (один кожаный портфель у меня есть).

(2) Я хочу купить другой, кожаный,  портфель (портфель есть, но не кожаный).

(3) Я хочу купить другой, кожаный портфель (портфель есть, но не кожаный).

Варианты 2 и 3 по смыслу одинаковы, различаются только интонацией, поэтому вариант 2 для ТАКОЙ ТЕМАТИКИ практически не употребляется, а используется вариант 3.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае мы имеем дело не с уточнением и не с однородными определениями, а с пояснительным определением (второе поясняет первое, между ними можно вставить союз *то есть* или *а именно*). Такие определения по правилу отделяются от поясняемого слова запятой.

*Вскоре мы вступим в новое, XXI столетие.*

*Очередной, шестой том подписного издания на днях поступит в магазин*.

*Четвёртая, последняя часть романа завершится эпилогом.*

Уточнение - это сужение объема понятия: *Длинная, в несколько верст, тень ложилась от гор на степи.*

А пояснение - одно и то же другими словами: *Внутри дома комнаты были наполнены заурядною, нехитрой мебелью.*

Но на практике отличить пояснительное определение от уточняющего и от однородного бывает трудно, тем более что в учебниках полно противоречивых примеров.

Comment: Различить уточняющее и пояснительное определения, действительно, бывает сложно, так что иногда лучше этим вовсе не заниматься. (В частности в нашем случае это все-таки уточнение - подстановка пояснительных союзов там как-то не к месту).Но дело-то вот в чем: уточняющие и пояснительные члены имеют одинаковую пунктуацию - они ОБОСОБЛЯЮТСЯ запятыми с двух сторон. А пояснительные и однородные члены также бывают ПОХОЖИ по смыслу, если раскрывают одну тему, но вот пунктуация у них разная, и именно на это следует обратить внимание.

Comment: ПРИМЕРЫ. "Чичиков немного озадачился таким, отчасти резким, определением. Здесь пояснение с обособлением, но встречается оформление без запятых (как неоднородные члены). "Своеобразие  явления проявляется в наличии "собственных", только ему присущих элементов". А здесь пояснение, оформленное как однородные отношения.

Comment: Уточняющие и пояснительные члены действительно обособляются с двух сторон, кроме пояснительных определений (они второй запятой не закрываются). В примере с Чичиковым - уточнение, а не пояснение (если верить Розенталю). Во втором примере - как раз пояснительное определение. А в целом тема порядком запутанная.

Comment: Пример с Чичиковым - это именно пояснение, так как раскрывается значение местоимения. Второй случай: если это пояснение, то почему слово не обособляется запятыми?

Comment: Уточнения соотносятся с уточняемым как общее и частное, широкое и конкретное, родовое и видовое. Из Розенталя: "Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений этот, тот, такой и др., например: Чичиков немного озадачился таким, отчасти резким, определением". При пояснении сужения объема понятия не происходит: собственные, только ему присущие элементы. Проблема различения в том, что и уточнения, и пояснения конкретизируют смысл, но, видимо, по-разному (надо будет посмотреть публикации по логике).

Comment: Однородные определения находятся в одинаковых отношениях к определяемому слову и между собой связаны перечислительной интонацией, а пояснительное определение относится к поясняемому определению. Почему вторая запятая не ставится, не знаю. В учебниках сказано, что это особый случай пояснения.